# Мгновенная регистрация

Tags: php, регистрация

Приветствую всех.

У меня возник вопрос и что-то я зашёл в тупик по поводу него. Задумал сделать мгновенную регистрацию - ввод электронной почты, без подтверждения и последующий вход по ней.

Мой вариант, так-как нельзя, чтобы любой мог зайти на чужой аккаунт:

1. Email + user_agent - совместить, создать хеш. И проверять его при входе, но при этом пользователь сможет заходить только с одного пк. И это не самый безопасный метод.

Может у кого ещё есть какие идеи?

Comment: Полная фигня. За юзер-агента - отрывать выступающие части тела. Реальный пример - у меня дома пять компьютеров, все с разными ОСями и браузерами. Разрешения экранов тоже разные. Получается, на Вашем сервисе мне придется регать пять аккаунтов? Что за бред? Лучше уж по старинке - логин+пароль. Активацию на имейл, так и быть, можно не слать. Но попрошу обратить внимание на один существенный момент. Кто-то может зарегистировать аккаунт с моим почтовым ящиком. И что дальше? Как поступить в такой ситуации?

Comment: Мне нужно работать именно по Email.
documentoved.ru - вход по Email, удобно и быстро.
По поводу регистрации - после входа, если пользователь - что-то собирается покупать - ему нужно подтвердить данный Email. А неактивные аккаунты удаляются спустя 7 дней.

Comment: Почему бы не сделать вход через vkontakte например?

Comment: Не вариант.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вводим почту, на почту приходит суперсекретносгенеренныйключ - например,

```
sha1(random(1,1000000).time().$mail);
```

по нему и входим. В базе хранится (ключ, почта). Грубо говоря, вход по паролю без логина. Самому придумывать пароль нельзя, так как легкий легко совпадет с кем-то еще.

Comment: Такой пароль запомнить нужно ещё :(

Comment: Копировать будут. Из почты.
Ну вы сами подумайте.
Ваша задача: сделать вход по ОДНОМУ полю. Для тысячи пользователей оно должно иметь длину МИНИМУМ 2 символа (цифры, буквы). Но в этом случае его будет легко подобрать.
Для того чтобы усложнить подбор давным-давно придумали пару логин-пароль. Грубо говоря, это искусственное удлиннение пароля. Дальнейшее развитие этого метода - вырожденная форма соли.

Значит, чтобы компенсировать отсутствие логина, вам придется самому удлиннять пароль.

Comment: Да, думаю ваш ответ будет идеальным в моём случае.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону регистрации по OpenId или OAuth, как пример (здесь доступна такая регистрация)

Comment: Всё бы хорошо, но в моей аудитории целевой - есть такие пользователи, которые про это ничего не знают! :)